# Any alternatives to this simple Javascript validation?

Tags: javascript, validation

Can anyone tell me what are the alternatives to validate user input? this is just a very basic code I wrote today.

- there is a button coded in HTML
- when the user click on it, it will prompt for input
- the input is only numbers

```
var a, b;
function cal(){
    a = prompt("enter the width");
        while(isNaN(a) || a <= 0 || a > 1000){
        alert("Invalid Input, enter it again!");
        return cal();
            }
    b = prompt("enter the length");
        while(isNaN(b) || b <= 0 || b > 1000){
        alert("Invalid Input, enter it again!");
        return cal();
            }
    result(a,b);
    }
function result(a,b){
    var perimeter = (2*a)+(2*b);
    var area = (a*b);
    document.write("Perimeter: "+perimeter+"<br>");
    document.write("Area: "+area+"<br>");
    }
```

Comment: search google for jquery validation plugin.

Comment: My example http://jsfiddle.net/nCV4w/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to use the new HTML5 input types and fall back to something like [this](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml)
if the browser does not support the new input type yet.

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="1000" />
```

But don't forget you still must do server side validation!

There are many great resources online and on SO on how to do this.

[HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

Comment: Good suggestion. One nitpick...in order to replicate what the original code is doing, the OP would also have to use the mix, max attributes as well.

Comment: @Haohmaru, I just started javascript today, so only touching on the basic stuff, didn't know much about PHP or any server-related languages.But thanks anyway

Comment: @vincentChen cool buddy, may i suggest reading through the awesome [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript?menu) docs, and here's a +1 to get you going on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex in your confirms:

```
var ptrn=/\D/g; // 'D' is any non-digit
if(ptrn.test(b) || b <= 0 || b > 1000){
    alert("Please enter only integers between 0 and 1000!");
    return cal();
}
```

Comment: regex is only use to validate numeric input right? I already done that using "isNaN". Isn't it the same?

Comment: No, this is a non-digit pattern I have shown. `isNaN` would return false for any number (or true if you use `!isNaN`, including decimal or negatives or anything that can be coerced to a number. This means 1.5 would pass a `isNaN` test with 0-1000 bounds.